# change Appendix numbering from A to 1

Tags: numbering, appendices

I use `\appendix` for mack appendix in book. I want change `Appendix` to `Appendix 1`or `Appendix first`. can you help me, please?

Comment: This depends a little bit on the documentclass. Can you help us, please? ;-)

Comment: that is book documentclass

Comment: This would mean that there are multiple chapters with number 1 etc. in the TOC, for example

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

This uses `\renewcommand{\thechapter}{...}` to change the chapter counter format to be either `\arabic{chapter}` or `\Ordinalnumber{chapter}`, depending on the conditional `\ifarabicappendix`.

Say `\arabicappendixtrue` to get the number output, otherwise keep it to `\arabicappendixfalse` for the output `Appendix First` etc.

However, if the 'number' format of the appendix is changed, this will lead to strings in the ToC, overprinting the appendix chapter title. It's better to add some more space to the number width box of the section number, in this case, this is done by writing `\addtolength{\cftchapnumwidth}{30pt}` to the ToC explicitly. The value of `30pt` can be changed of course.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage{fmtcount}


\newif\ifarabicappendix
\arabicappendixfalse

\ifarabicappendix

\xapptocmd{\appendix}{\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}}}{}{}
\else

\xapptocmd{\appendix}{\addtocontents{toc}{\addtolength{\cftchapnumwidth}{30pt}}\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Ordinalstring{chapter}}}{}{}
\fi


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Normal chapter}
\appendix

\chapter{First appendix chapter}
\chapter{Other appendix chapter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Isn't `\xapptocmd{\appendix}{...}` sufficient? What's the purpose of the conditional? If one wants to return to the previous condition, all it's needed is to comment out the line. I also recommend `\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}`.

Comment: The conditional is done on purpose to make it harder to change it somewhere. It can be removed of course. I agree with the `titles` option of tocloft.